# Compilation failing on mac os x 10.10

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc, clang

I'm trying to install the icsiboost library (https://github.com/benob/icsiboost). I had it installed on my previous machine (OS X 10.8) but now, on OS X 10.10.3, it gives me a weird error and I cannot figure why (BTW, it works like a charm on Ubuntu 14.10). From the error message, it looks like it's prepending symbols with a `_`. This is the error message: (I have run `./configure` before this)

`make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in src
gcc  -fnested-functions -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib   -o icsiboost icsiboost.o vector.o string.o hashtable.o array.o mapped.o threads.o debug.o file.o common.o  -lz -lpthread -lpcre -lm 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_vector_get_float", referenced from:
      _compute_classification_error in icsiboost.o
  "_vector_get_int32_t", referenced from:
      _train_text_stump in icsiboost.o
      _train_abstaining_text_stump in icsiboost.o
      _compute_test_error in icsiboost.o
      _compute_classification_error in icsiboost.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [icsiboost] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Did you run `./configure`?

Comment: yes, I do run ./configure

Comment: doesn't look like it's building with xcode (`xcodebuild`) so you are just using command line tools (adding clang tag also because gcc is clang on os x)